# Removing duplicates by first column but keep second

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I'm in need of a script that'll group the 2nd column/s to the first occurrence of the 1st column.

Example below:

input,

```
A,1
A,2
B,1
D,1
A,3
B,2
```

output,

```
A,1,2,3
B,1,2
D,1
```

Comment: What have you tried?  In what ways did what you tried fail to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -st, -g 1 collapse 2 < input.csv
A,1,2,3
B,1,2
D,1
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** using associative array `b` indexed on a counter `nukes` (stands for -- number of unique keys-- seen so far) and associative array `a` holding the actual data to be output. The purpose of the b array is to impose an order on the keys of array a. OTW, we get a random order when they are accessed (while printing in the END block)

```
$ awk -F ',' '
(newkey = !($1 in a)) {
  b[++nukes] = $1
}
{
  a[$1] = (newkey ? $1 : a[$1]) FS $2
}
END {
  for (i=1; i<=nukes; ++i) {
    print a[b[i]] 
  }
}
' your_file
```

**python** has ordered dictionaries which preserve the insertion order.

```
$ python3 - your_file <<\eof
import sys 
from collections import OrderedDict
h = OrderedDict()
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for l in f:
    for k, v in [l.rstrip('\n').split(',')]:
      h[k] = (h[k] if k in h else k) + ',' + v
print(*list(h.values()), sep='\n') 
eof
```

**GNU sed**:  we store the previously matched pattern in hold and look for the current line's first field in the hold and update the hold if found or simply append the line into hold. Print hold at eof.

```
$ sed -Ee 'G
  /^([^,]+)(,[^\n]+)\n((.*\n)?\1,[^\n]+)/{s//\3\2/;$q;h;d;} 
  s/\n.*//;H;1h;$!d;x
' your_file
```

**perl**:  taking a similar approach using hashes to uniquify keys.

```
perl -F, -lane '
  my($k, $v) = @F;
  my $seen = exists $h{$k};
  ($h[@h], $v) = ($k, $_) if ! $seen;
  push @{$h{$k}}, $v}{$,=",";
  print @{$h{$_}} for @h;
' your_file
```